# Greendao takes much time to generate class android

Tags: android, greendao, android-database

I am using Greendao to generate the class but it takes much time to generate the classes.

It has been more minutes, it's still keep on displaying Gradle build using task.

Below is screenshot

[image]

Based on this reference, I [applied](https://www.codementor.io/sundayakinsete/integrating-greendao-into-your-android-application-yro5fzgtw) greendao.

It has been more than 20 minutes but still it's not completed.

I selected invalidate cache and restart but still no use.

Comment: Make sure enough net speed & share build.gradle if possible

Comment: yes it's net speed is high only. :( but i am clueless how it's taking too much time.

Comment: Other gradle plugins are working fine in other project.

Comment: Probably, the problem is from their end because in today's my case, it took around 13 minutes to sync gradle irrespective of high speed net